# Is there a way to shift data in an attribute table so that all attributes are moved to a different coordinate?

Tags: qgis, data, attribute-table

I have several shapefiles where the attribute table is composed of timestamped data that is appended to the coordinates. Because of the nature of my data, I need to apply a time lag so that the data from a given time are placed a few minutes before. In other words, in Excel I would just delete the desired number of cells and have everything shifted up to the new coordinates.

The reason I do not do it in Excel is that I need to perform 'trial and error' until I find the right time lag to apply and it would be a lot faster if I could do it straight in QGIS where I can visually explore my data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new field and calculate the timestamp based on the existing timestamp plus/minus your time delay.  You can then try any time delay you like and is more elegant than shifting partial rows or creating a table-join (though that would work just fine too).  Do this by opening the attribute table, click the yellow pencil to make the layer editable and then click the 'abacus' button (last on the right).

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to do this.

I created a new field (called it joinfield) with the $rownum expression I created a set of consecutive numbers (1,2,3...).

I duplicated the attribute table, created another joinfield, amd this time I used $rownum - x (the time lag you want to apply, in my case, 8 minutes).

If the delay is the other way around you can use the (+) expression instead of (-).

And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

a quick solution (without coding), is to copy your table in a stand alone table, then join based on a ID field. When you change the value of your ID field (for instance ID = ID +1), the joined values will "move".